# BeautifulSoup error handling when find returns NoneType

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I am scraping search results from a website where each result is contained in a  and has a range of data associated with it. However some of these data values are missing and when they are, the error ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'' is returned.

I have put in a try/except block. Currently the entire search result is skipped when one of the values is missing. What can I do to allow the missing values to be replaced with a "", or blank in the xls file I am saving to?

My code is below:

```
divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="result-item standard") + soup.find_all("div", class_="result-item standard  basic-ad")     
for div in divs:
    try:
        #item_title = " ".join(div.h2.a.text.split())
        item = div.h2.a.text.split()
        item_year = item[0]
        item_make = item[1]

        item_model = ""
        for i in range (2,len(item)):
            item_model = item_model + item[i] + " "

        item_eng = div.find("li", "item-engine").text
        item_trans = div.find("li", "item-transmission").text
        item_body = div.find("li", "item-body").text
        item_odostr = div.find("li", "item-odometer").text
        item_odo = ''.join(c for c in item_odostr if c.isdigit())
        item_pricestr = " ".join(div.find("div", "primary-price").text.split())
        item_price = ''.join(c for c in item_pricestr if c.isdigit())
        item_adtype = div.find("div", "ad-type").span.text
        #item_distance = div.find("a", "distance-from-me-link").text
        item_loc = div.find("div", "call-to-action").p.text
        item_row = (str(x),item_year,item_make,item_model,item_eng,item_trans,item_body,item_odo,item_price,item_adtype,item_loc)
        print ",".join(item_row)
        print(" ")

        for i in range(len(item_row)):
            ws.write(x,i,item_row[i])

        if x % 500 == 0 :
            wb.save("data.xls")


    except AttributeError as e:
        with open("error"+str(x)+".txt", "w+") as error_file:
            error_file.write(div.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Put `try except` block for each `xxx.find().xxx` statement!

Comment: I think it's a great question. I bet you come from other language than Python, because I feel the same frustration, coming from Kotlin/Java in terms of handling null values in most of Python libs... too bad it's "pythonic way" to repeat the same peace of code in expressions like this post's answear. Best regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example:

```
item_eng = div.find("li", "item-engine").text if div.find("li", "item-engine") else ''
```

or:

```
item_eng = div.find("li", "item-engine").text if len(div.find_all("li", "item-engine"))!=0 else ''
```