# Keep blank where the user information is missing while scraping data in pandas

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python and using Beautiful soup is something which I am not familiar with. Basically Trying to scrape data using beautiful soup but I got stuck, actually for a particular profile I am extracting name, connection, location, company, etc.. from a profile. If in case any one of these Information is missing the code throws an IndexError..

here's the part of the code, what i am trying the way to scrape -

```
#experience setion
exp_section = soup.find('section', {'id': 'experience-section'})
exp_section = exp_section.find('ul')
div_tag = exp_section.find('div')
a_tag = div_tag.find('a')
job_title = a_tag.find('h3').get_text().strip()
company_name = a_tag.find_all('p')[1].get_text().strip()
joining_date = a_tag.find_all('h4')[0].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
exp = a_tag.find_all('h4')[1].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
info.append(company_name)
info.append(job_title)
info.append(joining_date)
info.append(exp)
info
```

Now in the profile i have checked the few details are missing thats why the code is not efficient to skip  the missing info if its blank and it gives error -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-dd2a258c45e4> in <module>
     17 a_tag = div_tag.find('a')
     18 job_title = a_tag.find('h3').get_text().strip()
---> 19 company_name = a_tag.find_all('p')[1].get_text().strip()
     20 joining_date = a_tag.find_all('h4')[0].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
     21 exp = a_tag.find_all('h4')[1].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
```

***Logic*** - I want it to be like if there is any information which is missing then the code must skip that and proceed scraping other data instead of giving error

I want my OP to be -

| name | location | connection | company | position | duration | tenure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tre Sayles | San Jose, California, United States | 500+ connections | Jacobs | Nan | 5 yrs 9 mos | Nan |

here's the code I have uploaded in wetransfer - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c507a3d20a16e536bb8bd7aae9fd8e6d20210322074309/c32af9

Please help me to make the code more efficient and error free..thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT** - *I have added how I want my OP should be*

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate question. You need to do if/else or try/catch statement for every columns you extract.

[BeautifulSoup error handling when find returns NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774409/beautifulsoup-error-handling-when-find-returns-nonetype)

Comment: If I want to use try-except then...what changes I will have to perform?

Comment: Actually, I'll recomment if/else because you can write in one line. But If you want to use try/except try code following try: company_name = a_tag.find_all('p')[1].get_text().strip() except IndexError: company_name =float("nan")